# Dynamically constructed textbox positioning

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a program where you can create rectangles and modify their length based on a textbox that should appear slightly above the rectangle and appear /2 of its width.

So far with this program you can draw the rectangle using your mouse and I made it so when you release the mouse it runs a method and creates these dynamic textboxs.

```
public void mainCounter()
{
     Textbox aboveBox = new TextBox();
     aboveBox.Name = Convert.ToString(_mainRectangle.Width);
     aboveBox.Left = _mainRectangle.Width / 2;
     aboveBox.Top = _mainRectangle.Height + 5;
     panel1.Controls.Add(aboveBox);
}
```

So what I am wanting to happen should look something like a rectangle with a textbox hovering above the center of its head once drawn but what im getting is a textbox that is appearing on a set part of the Y axis and if i draw different rectangles it appears in different locations on the X axis but its always there at the same place on the Y axis.

Screen shot:

[image]

This could be just something stupid im doing again and I apologize if that is the case but any help would be great. Thanks guys!

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `_mainRectangle`? It seems like `_mainRectangle.Height` is not returning what you expect it to return.

Comment: The code for it is just  'Rectangle _mainRectangle' and it describes the rectangle that i use to draw using mousedown. '_mainRectangle = new Rectangle(startpoint.X, startpoint.Y, width, height)'

Comment: Also add an image of what is happening with this code

Comment: imgur.com/kO2yCF0 the cyan colored rectangle is the rectangle i created and the numbered textboxs are appearing way up there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the coordinates wrong if you wanted to place the textbox centered. Note in particular you did not *position* the textbox in relation to the *position* of the rectangle (Left, Top), which I assume is an error.

If you want some object drawn adjacent to some other object, you should in general always do something like

```
A.Left = B.Left + ...
A.Top = B.Top + ...
```

Try this

```
Textbox aboveBox = new TextBox();
aboveBox.Name = Convert.ToString(_mainRectangle.Width);
aboveBox.Width = ...
aboveBox.Left = _mainRectangle.Left + (_mainRectangle.Width - aboveBox.Width) / 2;
aboveBox.Top = _mainRectangle.Top - aboveBox.Height - 5;
panel1.Controls.Add(aboveBox);
```

or something like it

Comment: thank you very much this works great and i see my mistake!